# How to initialize without showing values in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

When I initialize values to use later in Shiny, that initialized value shows on the app screen. Is there a way to only initialize without showing the value?

I've looked at the documentation with no success. reactiveValues seemed somewhat relevant, but it kept returning an error: `All arguments passed to reactiveValues() must be named.`

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example to help demonstrate what you mean. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the error when I pass a value directly to `reactiveValues`. `reactiveValues` require named parameters like in a named list. Think of it as the `input` variable in Shiny.

If you only need a single reactive value you can use `reactiveVal` instead.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  verbatimTextOutput("text1"),
  verbatimTextOutput("text2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  x <- reactiveVal(1)
  x_list <- reactiveValues('a'=1,'b'=2)
  # x_list <- reactiveValues(2) reproduces the given error


  output$text1 <- renderText(x())
  output$text2 <- renderText(paste(x_list$a, x_list$b))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I see - thank you! Is there a way to store values like ```average <- rnorm(10000, .03055, .01)```?

Comment: If you mean that you want your object `average` in the form of a reactive variable, then yes, you can use either one `average <- reactiveVal(rnorm(10000, .03055, .01))` or
`x_list <- reactiveValues('average'=rnorm(10000, .03055, .01))`

Comment: However, if you want the mean and sd values to be passed through user input, I'd suggest you use `reactive` or `eventReactive` (in case the value is changed on a trigger like a button or something) to create reactive values that can be used throughout the application.